# Debugging invisible JSON errors using php encoded variables, parsed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm using php json_encode to send a bunch of values to a client, where jquery

```
{"data":{"application":{"basics":{"email":"jepp@mily.com","name_first":"Step","name_last":"Bob","phone":"9210938102938","occupation":"unemployed","website":"wwwcom"},"application":{"title":"Default title","guid":"9as8ua9sd8ua9sdu","language":"sv"},"job":{"title":"joburl","url":"joburl"},"letter":{"letter":"abadbabkbakbakbakbakbakbabk"},"work-experiences":[{"title":"Default WORK Experience Title","url":"wwwsscom","date_from":"1970-01-01","date_to":"1999-12-31"},{"title":"Default WORK Experience Title","url":"wwwsscom","date_from":"1970-01-01","date_to":"1999-12-31"},{"title":"Default WORK Experience Title","url":"wwwsscom","date_from":"1970-01-01","date_to":"1999-12-31"}],"educations":{"title":"Default Education","url":"ixi","date_from":"1970-01-01","date_to":"1999-12-31"},"skills":{"title":"Defailt SKILL","url":"wwwsdcom","date_from":"ixi","date_to":"ixi"},"work-samples":{"title":"A sample of my work","url":"wwwsdcom","date_from":"ixi","date_to":"1999-12-31"}}},"error":[],"warning":[]}
```

If I try to parse this with `$.parseJSON` in a script I get no object. However, if I copy/paste it directly into the console (and add ' in the beginning and end), it works. There are no error codes and I can see no linebreaks. JSON lint-tools returns no errors...

I have set the correct content type and tried the different json parsers that jquery provides.

What have I missed?

---

The code was cut/pasted from the jQuery tutorials. I tried some different examples but they all failed.

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "application_controller.php", function() {
    console.log( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
})
.always(function(data) {
    console.log( "complete" );
    application = data;  
});

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function() {
    console.log( "second complete" );
});
});
```

---

It's true, I decoded it in the console. this is a snippet that does in in-script (it also won't work):

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: 'application_controller.php',
  data: '{id:id}',
  success: function( data ) {
        application = data.responseText;
        application = $.parseJSON(application);/* < string */     
    },
    fail: console.log("fail"),
    complete: function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
        application = data.responseText;
    }
});
```

Comment: Show us the ajax function where you're trying to parse it

Comment: As a sidenote, if you've set the dataType to JSON, it's already parsed, and parsing it again will cause an error.

Comment: You're using getJSON, so the JSON is already parsed, but it's also asynchronous, and where exactly are you trying to do this parsing ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

To solve this error I had to change all my php files from "utf8" encoding to "utf8 without BOM". Then it worked.

When a file without utf8 encoding was included (low in the hierarchy of course) it tainted all the other files and corrupted the output.

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse(jsonString) function.

```
var jsonString = '{"data":{"application":{"basics":{"email":"jepp@mily.com","name_first":"Step","name_last":"Bob","phone":"9210938102938","occupation":"unemployed","website":"wwwcom"},"application":{"title":"Default title","guid":"9as8ua9sd8ua9sdu","language":"sv"},"job":{"title":"joburl","url":"joburl"},"letter":{"letter":"abadbabkbakbakbakbakbakbabk"},"work-experiences":[{"title":"Default WORK Experience Title","url":"wwwsscom","date_from":"1970-01-01","date_to":"1999-12-31"},{"title":"Default WORK Experience Title","url":"wwwsscom","date_from":"1970-01-01","date_to":"1999-12-31"},{"title":"Default WORK Experience Title","url":"wwwsscom","date_from":"1970-01-01","date_to":"1999-12-31"}],"educations":{"title":"Default Education","url":"ixi","date_from":"1970-01-01","date_to":"1999-12-31"},"skills":{"title":"Defailt SKILL","url":"wwwsdcom","date_from":"ixi","date_to":"ixi"},"work-samples":{"title":"A sample of my work","url":"wwwsdcom","date_from":"ixi","date_to":"1999-12-31"}}},"error":[],"warning":[]}';

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/rbNHR/)